# White nodata values instead of black

Tags: c#, image, gis, jpeg, gdal

I have a problem. I cut a map on tiles using `gdal_csharp.dll` library (working on `gdal_retile.py` script rewritten into `C#`). Everything works fine except one case. When I cut areas with `nodata` values (tiles on the borders) and save them as `JPEG` files, the `nodata` areas are black (and I need them white) - example tile included below. I tried to use `tBand.SetNoDataValue(0);` but sometimes black `not-nodata` values (e.g. city names, road names, etc.) contain white dots...

Example tiles: [Tile no1](http://s15.postimage.org/eldvuvx9n/qwe_00006_00023.jpg) and [Tile no2](http://s16.postimage.org/bxdtjdb0l/qwe_00001_00001.jpg)

I don't know how to set `SetNoDataValue(/* what to write in here? */)`... Maybe there's the other way to solve this problem?

Here's my method:

```
private void CreatePyramidTile(MosaicInfo levelMosaicInfo, int offsetX, int offsetY, int width, int height, string tileName, DataSource ogrds)
{
    double sx = levelMosaicInfo.ScaleX * _scaleFactor;
    double sy = levelMosaicInfo.ScaleY * _scaleFactor;

    AffineTransformDecorator dec =
        new AffineTransformDecorator(new[]
                                         {
                                             levelMosaicInfo.Ulx + offsetX*sx, sx, 0,
                                             levelMosaicInfo.Uly + offsetY*sy, 0, sy
                                         });

    Dataset sFh = levelMosaicInfo.GetDataSet((int) Math.Round(dec.Ulx),
                                             (int) Math.Round((dec.Uly + height*dec.ScaleY)),
                                             (int) Math.Round((dec.Ulx + width*dec.ScaleX)),
                                             (int) Math.Round(dec.Uly));

    if (sFh == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (ogrds != null)
    {
        var points = dec.PointsFor(width, height);
        AddFeature(ogrds, tileName, points);
    }

    DataType bt;
    if (_bandType == DataType.GDT_Unknown)
    {
        bt = levelMosaicInfo.BandType;
    }
    else
    {
        bt = _bandType;
    }

    double[] geotransform = { dec.Ulx, dec.ScaleX, 0, dec.Uly, 0, dec.ScaleY };
    int bands = levelMosaicInfo.Bands;

    Dataset tFh;
    if (_memDriver == null)
    {
        tFh = _driver.Create(tileName, width, height, bands, bt, _createOptions.ToArray());
    }
    else
    {
        tFh = _memDriver.Create(tileName, width, height, bands, bt, _createOptions.ToArray());
    }

    if (tFh == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Creation failed, terminating gdal_tile.");
    }

    tFh.SetGeoTransform(geotransform);
    tFh.SetProjection(levelMosaicInfo.Projection);
// I think, the problem occurs in this loop; I tried to set nodata values
    for (int band = 1; band < bands + 1; band++)
    {
        Band tBand = tFh.GetRasterBand(band);

        if (levelMosaicInfo.Ct != null)
        {
            tBand.SetRasterColorTable(levelMosaicInfo.Ct);
        }
        tBand.SetRasterColorInterpretation(levelMosaicInfo.Ci[band - 1]);
//                tBand.SetNoDataValue(0);
    }

    var res = Gdal.ReprojectImage(sFh, tFh, null, null, _resamplingMethod, 0, 0, null, null);

    if (res != 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Reprojection failed for " + tileName + ", error " + res + ".");
    }

    levelMosaicInfo.CloseDataSet(ref sFh);

    if (_memDriver != null)
    {
        Dataset ttFh = _driver.CreateCopy(tileName, tFh, 0, _createOptions.ToArray(), null, null);
        ttFh.Dispose();
    }

    tFh.Dispose();
}
```

**[EDIT]**
There's still the same problem... I changed the loop:

```
for (int band = 1; band < bands + 1; band++)
{
    Band tBand = tFh.GetRasterBand(band);
    tBand.Fill(255, 0);
    tBand.SetNoDataValue(255);

    if (levelMosaicInfo.Ct != null)
    {
        tBand.SetRasterColorTable(levelMosaicInfo.Ct);
    }
    tBand.SetRasterColorInterpretation(levelMosaicInfo.Ci[band - 1]);
}
```

Now I think that my problem can appear by my conversion method. The data I get, is in `8-bit` format - after reprojecting the tiles are 90% filled by black color. So first I convert the source data into `24-bit` using `pct2rgb.py` script (rewritten to `C#`).

Here's the code:

```
public Dataset Convert8To24Bit()
{
    Gdal.AllRegister();

    string[] argv = Gdal.GeneralCmdLineProcessor(_args, 0);

    int i = 1;
    while (i < argv.Count())
    {
        string arg = argv.ElementAt(i);
        switch (arg)
        {
            case "-of":
                i++;
                _format = argv[i];
                break;
            case "-b":
                i++;
                _bandNumber = int.Parse(argv[i]);
                break;
            case "-rgba":
                _outBands = 4;
                break;
            default:
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_srcFileName))
                {
                    _srcFileName = argv[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    Usage();
                }
                break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    string tmpFileName = _srcFileName + ".bak";

    // open source file
    Dataset srcDS = Gdal.Open(_srcFileName, Access.GA_ReadOnly);
    if (srcDS == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to open " + _srcFileName + ".");
    }

    Band srcBand = srcDS.GetRasterBand(_bandNumber);

    // ensure we recognise the driver
    Driver dstDriver = Gdal.GetDriverByName(_format);
    if (dstDriver == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("\"" + _format + "\" not registered.");
    }

    // build color table
    int[][] lookup = new int[4][];
    lookup[0] = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).ToArray();
    lookup[1] = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).ToArray();
    lookup[2] = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).ToArray();
    lookup[3] = new int[256];

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        lookup[3][i] = 255;
    }

    ColorTable ct = srcBand.GetRasterColorTable();

    if (ct != null)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < Math.Min(256, ct.GetCount()); i++)
        {
            ColorEntry entry = ct.GetColorEntry(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                switch (j)
                {
                    case 0:
                        lookup[j][i] = entry.c1;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        lookup[j][i] = entry.c2;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        lookup[j][i] = entry.c3;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        lookup[j][i] = entry.c4;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return srcDS;
    }

    // create the working file
    string tifFileName = string.Empty;
    if (_format.Equals("GTiff", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        tifFileName = tmpFileName;
    }
    else
    {
        tifFileName = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(tmpFileName).Name, "temp.gif");
    }

//            Driver gTiffDriver = Gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff");
    Driver gTiffDriver = Gdal.GetDriverByName("MEM");

    Dataset tifDS = gTiffDriver.Create(tifFileName, srcDS.RasterXSize, srcDS.RasterYSize, _outBands, DataType.GDT_Byte,
                                       new string[] {});

    // we should copy projection information and so forth at this point
    tifDS.SetProjection(srcDS.GetProjection());
    double[] geotransform = new double[6];
    srcDS.GetGeoTransform(geotransform);
    tifDS.SetGeoTransform(geotransform);

    if (srcDS.GetGCPCount() > 0)
    {
        tifDS.SetGCPs(srcDS.GetGCPs(), srcDS.GetGCPProjection());
    }

    // do the processing one scanline at a time
    for (int iY = 0; iY < srcDS.RasterYSize; iY++)
    {
        byte[] srcData = new byte[srcDS.RasterXSize*1];
        srcBand.ReadRaster(0, iY, srcDS.RasterXSize, 1, srcData, srcDS.RasterXSize, 1, 0, 0);

        for (int iBand = 0; iBand < _outBands; iBand++)
        {
            int[] bandLookup = lookup[iBand];

            int[] dstData = new int[srcData.Count()];
            for (int index = 0; index < srcData.Count(); index++)
            {
                byte b = srcData[index];
                dstData[index] = bandLookup[b];
            }

            tifDS.GetRasterBand(iBand + 1).WriteRaster(0, iY, srcDS.RasterXSize, 1, dstData,
                                                       srcDS.RasterXSize, 1, 0, 0);
        }
    }

//            if (tifFileName != _srcFileName)
//            {
//                tifDS = Gdal.Open(tifFileName, Access.GA_ReadOnly);
//                dstDriver.CreateCopy(_srcFileName, tifDS, 0, new string[] { }, null, null);;
//            }

    srcDS.Dispose();

    return tifDS;
}
```

Whole classes: [GdalRetile.cs](http://pastebin.com/N5wWDZnV) and [TiffConverter.cs](http://pastebin.com/8u1nYfHh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution for this! I have simply filled my `TEMP` image on white, that is a background for a result tile.

Changes made in `GetDataSet()` method:

`Dataset resultDS = _tempDriver.Create("TEMP", resultSizeX, resultSizeY, _bands, _bandType, new string[] { });`

Line above changed to:

```
Dataset resultDS = _tempDriver.Create("TEMP", resultSizeX, resultSizeY, _bands, _bandType, new string[] { });
for (int i = 1; i < _bands + 1; i++)
{
    Band band = resultDS.GetRasterBand(i);
    band.Fill(255, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For rasters, NoData is not always respected. JPEGs do not respect NoData metadata on most software. So if you have NoData of '0', this could be interpreted as the pixel value of black.  By default, rasters are filled with 0 or black. You only need to redefine what NoData is. If you want it to be white and your pixel type is Byte, then it should be 255.

As a suggestion, after creating the data set and before loading data, try this:

```
...
    Band tBand = tFh.GetRasterBand(band);
    tBand.Fill(255); // otherwise it is filled with 0
    tBand.SetNoDataValue(255); // set metadata
...
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, but check my edit, please. Maybe it's the problem... :(